# Is it possible to export a sql table to excel using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, export-to-excel

I have a webpage with an export button. Is it possible to export a sql table to excel when this button is pressed? I can do it with a gridview but would just like a simple button with code behind to do the work. Can someone point me in the direction I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it in excel you can use the following code. Select the data and put it in a Gridview and do the following.

```
Dim GridView1 As New GridView

SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM TableName"
GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1
GridView1.DataBind()

Response.Clear()
Response.Buffer = True
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.Charset = ""
Me.EnableViewState = False
Dim oStringWriter As New System.IO.StringWriter
Dim oHtmlTextWriter As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter)

GridView1.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter)

Response.Write(oStringWriter.ToString())
Response.End()
```

You can also format the Gridview to make it look good on the Excel Sheet.

Comment: Yes, I already used that code but the problem is it will only export what is shown in the gridview. Not all rows and columns since I have paging on and not all columns shown

Comment: No. You don't have to use the Gridview on the page. You can create a Gridview in the Code behind and get all the records... Check the updated code above.

Comment: I have applied the same code, still it doesn't work on my machine. Is there any need to change the above code to successfully run on .NET version 4.5   Thanks!

Comment: i am using it in asp.net environment

Comment: update: it worked with a little change- "I didn't need to have a `datagrid` on `.aspx` page. A `datagrid` created at `runtime` i.e. `.aspx.cs`  works too." 
Ps: Corrections are always welcome though.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a utility function you can use:

```
Public Shared Sub ExportToSpreadsheet(table As DataTable, filename As String)
    ' Get a hold of the HTTP context and clear it, because we are going to push the CSV data through the context
    Dim context = HttpContext.Current
    context.Response.Clear()

    ' Loop through each column in your data table
    For Each column As DataColumn In table.Columns
        ' Write column names
        context.Response.Write(column.ColumnName + ";")
    Next

    context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine)

    ' Loop through each row in the data table
    For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
        ' Loop through each column in row
        For i As Integer = 0 To table.Columns.Count - 1
            ' Write each column value
            context.Response.Write(row(i).ToString().Replace(";", [String].Empty) & ";")
        Next

        ' Write a new line between rows of data
        context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine)
    Next

    ' Set the content type and headers
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv"
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & filename & ".csv")
    context.Response.[End]()
End Sub
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
ExportToSpreadsheet(YourDataTable, "YourFileName")
```

Note: Since it is a `Shared` function, then you can put it in a utility class and do not need to instantiate (`New`) the class to use the function.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working but the file isnt very clean, it has a ton of ;;;;;;; and everything thing is in columnA anyway to make this cleaner?

Comment: The result is .csv not .xls. Problem occurs when the separator character in windows is not ; but e.g. , (default in English?).

Comment: I changed csv to xls and it helped a little but now column names a split up just really messy. Yes english